# install ImageMagick on xampp

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I want to use ImageMagick in one of my project. Currently i am using

```
PHP version: 5.5.9
Windows Version: Windows 8 Pro  64-bit
XAMPP Version: 1.8.3
Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
```

i want to install ImageMagick 6.7.6 because it is already installed on my server where i want to deploy my project but this is not important i just want to install imageMagick on Xampp

this is what i tried

```
1 Add php_imagick.dll in C:\xampp\php\ext
extension=php_imagick.dll in php.ini C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

Now i restart windows and when i lunch xampp it says

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' 
- %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Please point me in right direction and tell me how can i install ImageMagick in xampp

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening, because you probably have downloaded the `x64` version of ImageMagick, but the architecture of your operating system does not mean that your php version is also `x64` - you can check it by running `phpinfo()` and look at the `Architecture` part.

What you have to do is really simple. Download the `x86` dll file and replace the old one in `C:\xampp\php\ext`

Also, there is no need to restart windows. An Apache restart from the xampp control panel will do the job.

Comment: will you please provide me the link that you think is matched with my version

Comment: @user3713959 You have to take a look what ImageMagick is offering for doawnload. Don't be lazy!